# binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&str`

Tags: string, rust

```
pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let mut rev = "";

    for n in x.to_string().chars().rev() {
        rev += n
    }

    return false
}
```

I'm used to writing this syntax in languages like kotlin, but how should I do this in rust?

Comment: Use `String`, not `&str`.

Answer (score 3):

`""` is an empty [string-slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), i.e. a reference to the storage where a sequence of utf-8 characters is placed (actually, it's a sequence of bytes conforming to utf-8 encoding, but that is not exactly the main concern in this question).
In general, with a string-slice, nothing says how those characters were stored, thus we cannot change anything to this storage (extend/remove) and moreover a string-slice (`&str`) is a shared (immutable) reference to this storage preventing from any change.
In this peculiar case (a literal as `" ... "`) the characters are stored in constant memory (consistent with a shared reference) at the process startup.

To extend such a sequence, you need to control **how** it is stored.
In this case, we don't use a string-slice but a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) which allocates on the heap the storage for the sequence according to the needs.
And, of course, since a `String` **owns** its content, it can mutate it (if the `String` itself is considered mutable).

Appending a `char` to a `String` is done with the [`.push()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) function.

```rust
pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let mut rev = String::new();

    for n in x.to_string().chars().rev() {
        rev.push(n);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I'd mention that `&str` doesn't own the data, but only references it immutably, so it can't modify it. While `String` does own the data and can therefore modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are of course correct and one of them should be the accepted answer.

I'd just like to point out that the construct `for n in iter { y.append(n) }` is used so many times that it got implemented in a method of `Iterator`: [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

```rust
pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let rev = x.to_string().chars().rev().collect::<String>();

    return false;
}
```

---

Another remark: to compute whether the forward and reverse of a string are identical, you don't actually need to create the reversed string. You can directly compare its iterators:

```rust
pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let x_str = x.to_string();
    x_str.chars().eq(x_str.chars().rev())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddAssign<&str>` is implemented for `String`. Thus you can use `+=` on `String`.

A simple example:

```rust
pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let mut rev = String::new();
    
    for n in x.to_string().chars().rev() {
        rev += &n.to_string();
    }
    
    return false
}
```